# Saving html5 canvas as an image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the facebook user's pics in my canvas which has a background image. Now I want to save my canvas as an image by default or on a button click. I have thorough research I found out it will done by using this

```
var myImage = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
imageElement.src = myImage;
```

but I am not able to figure out how to get it working with my code. I have tried all possiblities which I can think of. Its not working. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use toDataUrl on a canvas element after loading an image from another domain. This is a security issue specified by the [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements)

One way around this is if you have control over the server ***serving*** the images, you can then serve them with `access-control-allow-origin` headers. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#use-cases

Another option is to proxy the images from your server and thus your domain. instead of asking the images from the given url your js code will call a script on your server that will fetch the image and serve it to you.

In your case, you are attempting to grab images from facebook which obviously won't send those headers as this will be an enormous security problem. You will have to resort to a server side proxying solution.

Comment: But I have to do it, there must be some way??

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more info and a possible workaround